# Sharp.Xmpp FCM Upstream Messages

Tags: android, firebase, sharp.xmpp

I'm using `Sharp.Xmpp` to receive upstream messages from Android Device via FCM. It connects fine and 'at times' I can receive the messages sent from Android on my app server but the ratio is 50% whereas Android device gives a successful `onMessageSent` event.
The server side code is:

```
try {
     using (var cl = new XmppClient("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com", "Username", "Password", 5236, Sharp.Xmpp.Core.TLSMode.TLSSocket)) {

     // Setup any event handlers before connecting.
     cl.Message += OnNewMessage;

     // Connect and authenticate with the server.
     cl.Connect();

     SendPushNotification("Connected");

     cl.Close(); }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { SendPushNotification("Error Invalid: " + ex); }
catch (IOException ex) { SendPushNotification("Error IO: " + ex); }
catch (XmppException ex) { SendPushNotification("Error XMPP: " + ex); }
catch (NullReferenceException ex) { SendPushNotification("Error Null: " + ex); }
```

New Message Received event is

```
private void OnNewMessage(object sender, Sharp.Xmpp.Im.MessageEventArgs e) {
    SendPushNotification("Message from " + e.Jid + " " + e.Message.Body);
    div_View_Message.InnerHtml = "Message xyz " + e.Message.Body.ToString();
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and the `SendPushNotification(String str)` is Downstream messages with HTTP protocol. Android Device receives a push notification of 'connected' fine but the 'e.Message.Body' is received at times and not others. What should be added/removed?

Android Sends the messages as

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(new RemoteMessage.Builder("SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .setMessageId(Integer.toString(INT_VALUE)).addData("my_token", str).build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616048/firebase-upstream-cloud-messages?rq=1) question, XMPP must stay open at all times. Hence, switching for Web based application, that closes the connection after every few requests per second, to a Desktop application, hosted on a local server, solved the issue.

Also, it adding `setTtl(86400);` for message sending ensures `onMessageSent` call.